# Alert Controller Button Color in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertcontroller

I have the following implementation, which is actually an alert with two buttons. It works and functional.

The only issue that I have is to give different colors for these two buttons. Now, it has only one color which is red. But I want one of them to be green and other one to be red.

```
UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Message" message:nil preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

[alert addAction:[UIAlertAction
                  actionWithTitle:@"Cancel"
                  style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                  handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                  {

                  }]];


[alert addAction:[UIAlertAction
                  actionWithTitle:@"Apply"
                  style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                  handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                  {
                  }]];

alert.view.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Comment: There is no public API supporting what you want. You need a custom alert view.

Answer (score 2):

you can do like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];
   // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


  UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Message" message:nil preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

  UIAlertAction *defaultAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Default" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil];
  [defaultAction setValue:[UIColor redColor] forKey:@"_titleTextColor"];


  UIAlertAction *cancelAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:nil];
  [cancelAction setValue:[UIColor greenColor] forKey:@"_titleTextColor"];

  [alertController addAction:defaultAction];
  [alertController addAction:cancelAction];

  [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

[Running effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVFlI.png); Otherwise if you use UIAlertView not UIAlertController, You need custom the alert view.